# Powering Arduino and LED strips from one adapter

Tags: arduino-uno, led-strip

My project has my Arduino controlling 10 led strips. I'm going with a plan by @gre_gor that is posted here: [Setting 10 RGB Strips Independently from Single Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52685/setting-10-rgb-strips-independently-from-single-arduino)
...where each strip is controlled by an STM32 driver.

I'm packing all electronics into a tight space and will need to have the power adapter external with just the cable coming in.

I need power both to the arduino and directly to the stm32's.

Question: can I simply split the 12V power cable to send power to both the led strips and the arduino? Or is there something I should worry about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powering an Arduino and LED strips is no different to powering your TV, satellite receiver, DVD player, etc all from one socket in the wall.

Connect all the grounds (-) together, and connect all the powers (+) together.

All you need to worry about is that the total current draw of all the devices combined doesn't exceed the amount of current that the power supply can provide (oh, and that they all operate at the same voltage, of course).